# ThreadWaitReason - The thread is waiting for a virtual memory page to arrive in memory

Tags: c#, multithreading, process

I have a WPF (C# 3.5) app which have tons of threads... lately my threads are getting stuck on ThreadWaitReason PageIn (I've managed to discover it using Memory Profiler).
Tough I can understand the message I`m not sure on what it really means, and how can I avoid/workaround this problem...
Your help is really appreciated!
Thank you so much!

**Statistics**
Memory consumption: 456mb
Private bytes: 364mb
.NET private bytes usage: 150mb
ProcessThreads: 76 (all of them are in wait state, threadwaitreason: pagein

The tool is warning a message: "Memory fragmentation is restricting the size of objects that can be allocated."

Comment: What do you mean by "tons of threads"? How many threads go in a ton? (and note, this isn't an attempt at being funny, I'd really like to know how many threads you have in that app.)

Comment: `The thread is waiting for a virtual memory page to arrive in memory.`, use Windows task manager to see which application consumed all virtual memory

Comment: How many exactly is "tons of threads"? How much memory does the application consume? What is the normal CPU load? What exactly does "getting stuck" mean? How long are they "stuck" for?

Comment: I will update the statistics on the main question body shortly. tks!

Comment: By getting stuck I mean the application window hangs undefinetely.... CPU load is normal... no big issue here...

Comment: Buy more RAM like @HansPassant suggests, and maybe an SSD.  Are the threads doing something that requires frequent access to large numbers of pages?  Huge stack buffers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use up all of your available physical memory, you will end up paging to the disk which takes an enormous amount of time to read a page compared to the RAM. This is why your threads are waiting for pages to be loaded.

The warning you are mentioning is due to the fact that allocations and deallocations of memory result in the memory being fragmented with gaps between chunks of free memory. If the fragmentation is severe, the free chunks may be so small that you are not able to freely allocate memory as you wish.